# Fatal error: Call to a member function extended() on a non-object in

Tags: magento

> Fatal error: Call to a member function extended() on a non-object in /home/wholesal/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 600

Our magento site is currently down and receiving errors such as this one. We attempted to install an extension and after clicking the install we've been unable to access our site and are getting the error. Any ideas? Below is what line 600 looks like:

```
public function extended(Varien_Simplexml_Config $config, $overwrite=true)
{
    $this->getNode()->extended($config->getNode(), $overwrite);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Hi,Can you mention the extension that you tried to install so that we can have some idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be caused by incorrect file/folder permissions or broken XML structure.
Please check xml-files in app/etc and each custom module located in app/code/local/, app/code/community/ folders